# Problem with deletion of a map element and insertion of a new element in its place

Tags: c++, data-structures

This question is from the book "Jumping into C++", chapter 19.

> Write a program that reads in HTML text that the user types in (don’t worry, we’ll cover how to read from a file later). It should support the following HTML tags: <html>, <head>, <body>, <b>, <i>, and <a>. Each HTML tag has an open tag, e.g. <html>, and a closing tag which has a forwardslash at the start: </html>. Inside the tag is text that is controlled by that tag: <b>text to be bolded</b> or <i>text to be italicized</i>. The head> </head> tags control text that is metadata, and the <body> </body> tags surround text that is to be displayed. <a> tags are used for hyperlinks, and have an URL in the following format: <a href=URL>text</a>.
>
> Once your program has read in some HTML, it should simply ignore <html>. It should remove any text from the <head> section so that it doesn't show up when you output it. It should then display all text in the body, modifying it so that any text between <b> and </b> will show up with asterisks (*) around it, any text inside <i> and </i> will show up with underscores (_) around it, and any text with a <a href=linkurl>link text</a> tag shows up as link text (linkurl).

Brief explanation of my attempt
Step 1 - assigned the string between body tags to a new string variable  "body".
Step 2 - created a map "check" and inserted parts of the string in "body" leaving out the string between <b> </b> tags.
Step 3 - tried to replaced the inserted elements of map "check" which contain <i> </i> tags, by first assigning the values of `itr->first` and `itr->second` to new variables, then deleting that element and inserting new elements in map after removing string between <i> </i> tags.

**This is where I face the problem. The compiler doesn't give an error but the program doesn't return 0. If I remove the "check.erase(index)", it works, but that doesn't solve the purpose.**

I tried doing a similar thing in a separate code and it worked.  I have included the other code after the following one, which is the attempted solution to the question above.

```
int main()
{
map<int,string>check;

string x = "<html>";
string xx = "</html>";
string y = "<head>";
string yy = "</head>";
string z = "<body>";
string zz = "</body>";
string a = "<b>";
string aa = "</b>";
string b = "<i>";
string bb = "</i>";
string c = "<a href";
string ccc = ">";
string cc = "</a>";

string type = "<html>\n<head>I dont know what to write here</head>\n<body>\ngurasees is <b>my</b> good <i>name</i>. You can find <b>me</b> on the <i>web</i>. Link is <a href = www.google.com>gura</a>\n</body>\n</html>";

int f = type.find(z)+z.size()+1;
int g = type.find(zz)-f;
string body = type.substr(f,g);

 map<int,string>::iterator itr;
 map<int,string>::iterator ends = check.end();

 //--------------------------STEP 2-----------------------------------------

 check.insert ({body.find(body[0]), body.substr (body.find(body[0]), body.find(a,0)-1)});
 
int k = body.find(a, 0);
k++;
int p = body.find(aa,0);

for (int i = body.find(a,k); i != string::npos && p != string::npos; i = body.find(a, i), p = body.find(aa, p))
{
    check.insert({p+aa.size(),body.substr(p+aa.size(), i-1-(p+aa.size()))});
    i++; p++;
}
    check.insert({p + aa.size() , body.substr(p + aa.size() , body.size() - 1 - p ) } ) ;

 //------------------------STEP 3-------------------------------------------

for (itr = check.begin(); itr != ends; itr++)
{
    cout << itr->second.find(b) << endl; //prints out correctly
    if (itr->second.find(b) != string::npos)
    {
        int index = itr->first;
        string italic_component = itr->second;
        
        check.erase(index);
        check.insert ({index, italic_component.substr(italic_component.find(italic_component[0]), italic_component.find(b, 0)-1)});
        int u = italic_component.find(b, 0);
        u++;

        int j = italic_component.find(bb, 0);

        for (int i = italic_component.find(b, u); i != string::npos && j != string::npos; i = italic_component.find(b, u), j = italic_component.find(bb, j) )
        {
            check.insert({index + j + bb.size() , italic_component.substr(j + bb.size(), i - 1 - (j+bb.size()))});
            i++; j++ ;
        }

        check.insert({j + index + bb.size() ,italic_component.substr(j + bb.size() , italic_component.size() - 1 - j ) } ) ;
    }
}

//------------------------------STEP 4-------------------------------------

 for ( int i = body.find( a , 0 ), j = body.find( aa , 0), k = body.find( b , 0 ), l = body.find( bb , 0); i != string::npos && j != string::npos && j != string::npos && k != string::npos; i = body.find(a, i ), j = body.find(aa,j), k = body.find(b, k), l = body.find(bb,l) )
{
    check.insert( {i, "*" + body.substr(i+a.size(), j-(i+a.size())) + "*" } );
    check.insert( {k, "_" + body.substr(k+b.size(), l-(k+b.size())) + "_" } );
    i++; j++; k++; l++;
}
}
```

-------------------------THE OTHER CODE--------------------------------

```
int main()
{
map<int,string>check;

check[10] = "gurasees is there for you";
check[20] = "aka is not born yet";
check[30] = "sam please wait for years";

map<int,string>::iterator itr;
map<int,string>::iterator ends = check.end();

for(itr = check.begin(); itr!= ends; itr++)
{
    if(itr->second.find("born") != string::npos)
     {
         
         int index = itr->first;
         string italic = itr->second;

         check.erase(itr->first);
         

         check.insert({index, italic.substr(italic.find(italic[0]), 5)});
     }
}
```

Comment: what's this? `body.find(body[0])`, 0 it's enough.

Comment: Expanding on above, `body.find(body[0])` says  Return the index of the first place we can find the first character in the string. This will obviously be 0 unless the string is empty.

Comment: `erase`ing elements from a container while iterating through the container is almost always a mistake. Odds are good that you `erase` `itr.  Stepping through the program with a debugger will help you confirm or reject this likely possibility.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for the response. I've written what I tried in the answers section. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that now. `itr` keeps pointing to the memory that has been freed (I guess freed is the right word?) making the memory invalid to use. This invalidates the pointer as well, so trying to increment it will result in program crash.

I learnt through debugging (in the smaller code) that when I erased the memory `itr` is pointing to, it is allocated back after using `check.insert()` (after `check.erase()`). In that case there is no segmentation fault as `itr++` becomes valid. This is what was happening in the smaller code that I wrote, all of the times I ran it before I raised the question. Now that I started going through debugger again and again to understand what was happening, the program crashed a few times and I realised the problem.

Same with the main code, in that case commenting out L66 was making the code run smoothly without any segmentation fault. The reason was the same situation being repeated as described above.

But if I inserted another element (this means inserted 2 elements after deleting an element, once at L54 & another at L66 ), it was making it highly unlikely that the memory that was erased (that itr is still pointing to) will be allocated back again. Only once from all the times, the whole code ran, returning 0 in this case.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

So I reassigned `itr = check.begin()` after L66, making it valid again, which solves the problem.